# Запуск функций по таймеру?

Tags: windows, таймер, c, функции

Сейчас сделал через обработку `WM_TIMER`, но многие советуют этого не делать, так как страдает точность и какие-то ещё проблемы, которые я не узнавал. Так вот, как ещё можно сделать запуск функций по таймеру?
Если использовать какой-нибудь `GetTickCount()`, то в какое место программы его нужно добавлять, в `WM_CREATE` или ещё куда?
Желательно, чтобы код был на Си и с примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CreateWaitableTimer** или **CreateTimerQueue**, подробней смотрите Рихтера/MSND, там все описано и с примерами.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше оставить WM_TIMER. Второй вариант - вынести в отдельный поток функцию и вызывать Sleep. Но точность тоже будет хромать.